# Is it well defined to declare an object of the class before its static variable in global space?

Tags: c++, initialization, static-members, undefined-behavior

Following is a simple case of counting objects:

```
struct A
{
  static int count;
  A () { ++ count; }
};
```

Now, its object and `static` member are declared as:

```
A obj;  // comes 1st
int A::count = 5;  // comes 2nd
```

[g++ produces expected result](http://www.ideone.com/aO0h9). But since, definition of `A::count` comes after one of the `A` instance in global space, shouldn't it be **undefined behavior** ?

Comment: POD are zero-initialized. The forward declaration of the static really ought to be forward but it may depend on where A is declared is the scope be it global, a namespace, etc makes a significant difference as to how things are initialized.

Answer (score 2):

It depends.

3.6.2

> The storage for objects with static
>   storage duration (basic.stc.static)
>   shall be zero-initialized (dcl.init)
>   before any other initialization takes
>   place. Zero-initialization and
>   initialization with a constant
>   expression are collectively called
>   static initialization; all other
>   initialization is dynamic
>   initialization. Objects of POD types
>   (basic.types) with static storage
>   duration initialized with constant
>   expressions (expr.const) shall be
>   initialized before any dynamic
>   initialization takes place.

Since you have a POD initialized with a constant expression, it will be statically initialized, i.e. before any constructors run. Change any of these conditions, and unexpected results are likely to occur.

Comment: The results may be unexpected, but they will still be well defined even without the constant initialization.